# what should be the htaccess code for category and subcategory

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

what should be the htaccess code for a php site that diplay my category and subcategory as

sitename/category
sitename/category/sibcategory/
sitename/category/sibcategory/city/
sitename/category/sibcategory/city/detailpage.html

sitename/admin (for  administation )
sitename/users (for  user information)

Comment: You need to give some more information. Have you tried anything yourself? Done any research? Got specific errors?

Comment: i am using    RewriteRule ([^&]+)/$ /subcategory.php?cat_nm=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ([^&]+)-([^&]+)/$ /region.php?subct_nm=$2 [L]